# Use R to extract data for an identifier in a row and put it in a new column

Tags: r, loops, gis, watershed

I have some data that I used ArcGIS to get and I want to construct a database by watershed identifier (for example HUC_8=1404106). The data contains the watershed identifier (HUC_8), watershed Area, Soil type, and Soil Area. The watershed identifier is listed as many times as there are soil types. I want to create a database based on watersheds (having the identifier only appear once in the column) and extract the soil area by type in different columns. I attached a subset of the data so that hopefully it is clear. I am somewhat new to R, but I feel that this could be done with a for loop. Knowing how to do this would be extremely helpful, being that I work a lot with GIS, but would like to perform more analysis in R.

```
HUC_8   WatershedArea   Soil    SoilArea    A_Area  B_Area  C_Area  D_Area  Null_Area
14040106    461104.4883 B       96590.33424                 
14040106    461104.4883 C       86282.93487                 
14040106    461104.4883 D       24945.9992                  
14050007    921494.3621 Null    2.861388                    
14050007    921494.3621 A       87214.28385                 
14050007    921494.3621 B       131417.8659                 
14050007    921494.3621 C       268324.5125                 
14050007    921494.3621 D       314131.5806                 
14060001    627348.8316 Null    8119.375083                 
14060001    627348.8316 A       5315.511117                 
14060001    627348.8316 B       286915.9001                 
14060001    627348.8316 C       114357.5251                 
14060001    627348.8316 D       163671.7545
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially it sounds like you want to reshape your data from long format to wide format. The `reshape2` library can come in handy here

```
#sample data
dd<-read.table(text="HUC_8   WatershedArea   Soil    SoilArea
14040106    461104.4883 B       96590.33424                 
14040106    461104.4883 C       86282.93487                 
14040106    461104.4883 D       24945.9992                  
14050007    921494.3621 Null    2.861388                    
14050007    921494.3621 A       87214.28385                 
14050007    921494.3621 B       131417.8659                 
14050007    921494.3621 C       268324.5125                 
14050007    921494.3621 D       314131.5806                 
14060001    627348.8316 Null    8119.375083                 
14060001    627348.8316 A       5315.511117                 
14060001    627348.8316 B       286915.9001                 
14060001    627348.8316 C       114357.5251                 
14060001    627348.8316 D       163671.7545", header=T)
```

now transform the data

```
library(reshape2)

wide <- dcast(dd, HUC_8+ WatershedArea ~ Soil)

#change default column names
soils <- levels(dd$Soil)
names(wide)[match(soils, names(wide))] <- paste(soils,"Area",sep="_")
```

which results in the `wide` dataframe which looks like

```
     HUC_8 WatershedArea    A_Area    B_Area    C_Area   D_Area   Null_Area
1 14040106      461104.5        NA  96590.33  86282.93  24946.0          NA
2 14050007      921494.4 87214.284 131417.87 268324.51 314131.6    2.861388
3 14060001      627348.8  5315.511 286915.90 114357.53 163671.8 8119.375083
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Flick. I tried your method, but I get an error reading "Using SoilArea as value column: use value.var to override.". Not sure what that means

Comment: That's not an error. That's a warning. If you want you can explicitly set the value.var= parameter in the function call. I would encourage you to read the `?dcast` help page when learning a new function.

Comment: I tried it again on my larger dataset and I get an error (Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length). My code is below                                                   > Huc8Soil <- read.csv("Huc8_soils.csv")
> wide2 <- dcast(Huc8Soil, HUC_8+ WatershedArea ~ Hydro) ###Problem
Using SoilArea as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
> #change default column names
> soils <- levels(Huc8Soil$Hydro)
> names(wide2)[match(soils, names(wide2))] <- paste(soils,"Area",sep="_")

Comment: > wide2
      HUC_8 WatershedArea A_Area B_Area C_Area D_Area Null_Area
1  14010005      31458.13      0      0      1      0         0
2  14040106     461104.49      0      1      1      1         0
3  14040107     116521.39      0      0      0      1         0
4  14050007     921494.36      1      1      2      1         1
5  14060001     627348.83      1      1      1      1         1
6  14060002     412849.74      0      1      1      1         1
7  14060003    1693374.17      1      1      1      1         1
......

Comment: THanks for all of your help. I am sure it is something I am overlooking in my CSV file.

Comment: Sounds like you have duplicate ids and soil indicators in your real data. You can choose to sum or average the values depending on what the duplicate is meant to represent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
lst <- Map(function(x,y) ifelse(df$Soil==x,y, NA),
                     sort(unique(df$Soil)), list(df$SoilArea))
names(lst) <- paste(names(lst), 'Area', sep="_")
df[names(lst)]  <- lst

head(df,3)
#      HUC_8 WatershedArea Soil SoilArea A_Area   B_Area   C_Area D_Area
#1 14040106      461104.5    B 96590.33     NA 96590.33       NA     NA
#2 14040106      461104.5    C 86282.93     NA       NA 86282.93     NA
#3 14040106      461104.5    D 24946.00     NA       NA       NA  24946
#   Null_Area
#1        NA
#2        NA
#3        NA
```

#### Update

If you wanted to `reshape` from `long` to `wide`, you could also use `base R` `reshape`

```
df1 <- reshape(df, idvar=c('HUC_8', 'WatershedArea'),
                          timevar='Soil', direction='wide')

colnames(df1)[-(1:2)] <- paste0(gsub('.*\\.', '',
                           colnames(df1)[-(1:2)]), '_Area')
df1[,c(1:2,7,3:6)]
#     HUC_8 WatershedArea    A_Area    B_Area    C_Area   D_Area   Null_Area
#1 14040106      461104.5        NA  96590.33  86282.93  24946.0          NA
#4 14050007      921494.4 87214.284 131417.87 268324.51 314131.6    2.861388
#9 14060001      627348.8  5315.511 286915.90 114357.53 163671.8 8119.375083
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(HUC_8 = c(14040106L, 14040106L, 14040106L, 14050007L, 
14050007L, 14050007L, 14050007L, 14050007L, 14060001L, 14060001L, 
14060001L, 14060001L, 14060001L), WatershedArea = c(461104.4883, 
461104.4883, 461104.4883, 921494.3621, 921494.3621, 921494.3621, 
921494.3621, 921494.3621, 627348.8316, 627348.8316, 627348.8316, 
627348.8316, 627348.8316), Soil = c("B", "C", "D", "Null", "A", 
"B", "C", "D", "Null", "A", "B", "C", "D"), SoilArea = c(96590.33424, 
86282.93487, 24945.9992, 2.861388, 87214.28385, 131417.8659, 
268324.5125, 314131.5806, 8119.375083, 5315.511117, 286915.9001, 
114357.5251, 163671.7545)), .Names = c("HUC_8", "WatershedArea", 
"Soil", "SoilArea"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: THank you akrun, I appreciate it. That helps a lot, but I will still need only one row for each HUC_8 value.